# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[] & Iterable<any>'

Tags: angular

Hi i am trying to build a small angular application . I called an API and i am seeing the result in console . But when i try to iterate the result set in html i am getting an error as below .

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[] & Iterable<any>'
```

My Code in Componenet is

```
  apiResult={};
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.auditDetails.getAuditDataDetails().subscribe( (result)=> {
  console.warn(result)// Here i am seeing the result.
  this.apiResult = result
})
}
```

In HTML i am trying to iterate the result like below

```
<p *ngFor = "let item of apiResult" >
{{item.Name}}
</p>
```

ApiResult i am seeing like below

```
[{id="123",Name="VKP"},{id="923",Name="RKP"}]
```

What is the mistake i am doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API response is actually an `Array` of `Objects`. You are trying to assign an array of objects to an object.

Just reassign `apiResult={};` to `apiResult=[];` or  `apiResult:any= [];` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks , this one worked .
apiResult:any= [];